# Spark Streaming failed executor tasks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

When i look at Jobs tab on spark UI, i can see Tasks status like 20/20/ (4 failed).

Does it mean there is data loss on failed tasks? Aren't those failed tasks moved to a diff executor?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you should be wary of failing tasks (they are frequently an indicator of an underlying memory issue), you need not worry about data loss. The stages have been marked as successfully completed, so the tasks that failed were in fact (eventually) successfully processed.

Comment: Thank you Glennie.

Comment: @AKC Although tasks failing in general shouldn't be worrying, I tasks failing this often should definitely worry you. Can you add additional stacktrace and error message for the failed tasks?